# Optimising the time for deleting rows in excel vba

Tags: excel, vba

I want to delete some rows- 1000/10000 based on one condition but its taking too long time. I also tried all the solutions available on internet i.e. filter the data, `Application.ScreenUpdating = False`, setting timer etc.

```
Private Sub Remove_incomplete_records_Click()
Dim n, count As Integer
Dim i As Long
Dim lastrownum As Integer

lastrownum = Sheets("Master_Data").Cells(Rows.count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

Dim varCalcmode

Do While (lastrownum)
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False    
    'for NB,FO etc if field your refernence is not present then delete the entire row.    
    For i = 2 To lastrownum    
        If (Sheets("Master_Data").Cells(i, 2).Value <> "YC" And Sheets("Master_Data").Cells(i, 2).Value <> "YK" And Sheets("Master_Data").Cells(i, 2).Value <> "MK" And Cells(i, 2).Value <> "WK" And Sheets("Master_Data").Cells(i, 2).Value <> "AN") Then
            If (Sheets("Master_Data").Cells(i, 4).Value = "") Then
                On Error Resume Next
                Sheets("Master_Data").Rows(i).EntireRow.Delete Shift:=xlUp
                varCalcmode = Application.Calculation
                Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
                Application.ScreenUpdating = False
            Else
            End If
        Else
        End If
    Next i
Loop

Application.Calculation = varCalcmode
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Please suggest the faster way to do this operation.

Comment: Working from the last row upwards is a cheap to implement optimisation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give this a try instead. Instead of deleting the rows 1 by 1, it finds every row that fits the delete criteria and deletes them in one hit. Much more efficient

```vb
Private Sub Remove_incomplete_records_Click()
    Dim i As Long, LastRowNum As Long
    Dim DeleteRng As Range
    Dim varCalcmode As XlCalculation

    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = False
        varCalcmode = .Calculation
        .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    End With

    With Sheets("Master_Data")
        LastRowNum = .Cells(Rows.count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

        'for NB,FO etc if field your refernence is not present then delete the entire row.
        For i = 2 To LastRowNum

                If .Cells(i, 2).Value2 <> "YC" And .Cells(i, 2).Value2 <> "YK" And _
                    .Cells(i, 2).Value2 <> "MK" And Cells(i, 2).Value2 <> "WK" And _
                    .Cells(i, 2).Value2 <> "AN" And .Cells(i, 4).Value2 = vbNullString Then
                        If DeleteRng Is Nothing Then
                            Set DeleteRng = Sheets("Master_Data").Rows(i)
                        Else
                            Set DeleteRng = Union(DeleteRng, shets("Master_Data").Row(i))
                        End If
                    End If
                End If
        Next i
    End With

    If Not DeleteRng Is Nothing Then DeleteRng.EntireRow.Delete Shift:=xlUp

    With Application
        .Calculation = varCalcmode
        .ScreenUpdating = True
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: No problem - don't forget to click the tick next to the answer if it has solved your issue

Answer (score 0):

this method is faster.

```
Private Sub Remove_incomplete_records_Click()
Dim n, count As Integer
Dim i As Long
Dim lastrownum As Integer
Dim rngU As Range

    lastrownum = Sheets("Master_Data").Cells(Rows.count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

    Dim varCalcmode
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Do While (lastrownum)

        'for NB,FO etc if field your refernence is not present then delete the entire row.
        For i = 2 To lastrownum
            If (Sheets("Master_Data").Cells(i, 2).Value <> "YC" And Sheets("Master_Data").Cells(i, 2).Value <> "YK" And Sheets("Master_Data").Cells(i, 2).Value <> "MK" And Cells(i, 2).Value <> "WK" And Sheets("Master_Data").Cells(i, 2).Value <> "AN") Then
                If (Sheets("Master_Data").Cells(i, 4).Value = "") Then
                    'On Error Resume Next
                    With Sheets("Master_Data")
                        If rngU Is Nothing Then
                            Set rngU = .Range("a" & i)
                        Else
                            Set rngU = Union(rngU, .Range("a" & i))
                        End If
                    End With
                    'Sheets("Master_Data").Rows(i).EntireRow.Delete Shift:=xlUp
                    'varCalcmode = Application.Calculation
                    'Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
                    'Application.ScreenUpdating = False
                Else
                End If
            Else
            End If
        Next i
    Loop
    rngU.EntireRow.Delete
    'Application.Calculation = varCalcmode
    'Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Best solution. Thanks